# Adding Android jar files with relative path

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-library

I'm trying to add a jar file to my existing app. When I tried to the following 
absolute path to my build.gradle, it works fine.

```
compile files('C:/Users/julia/AndroidStudioProjects/TestProject/libs/MyPo.jar')
```

However, when I tried to change it to relative path, it doesn't work.

```
compile files('libs/MyPo.jar'), I also tried
compile project('libs:MyPo.jar')
compile project(':libs:MyPo.jar')
```

What's the proper way to add this jar file to my app using relative path? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the solution already in stackoverflow :. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16608135/3595514

Comment: Yah I saw that answer, but couldn't understand the second part (Right click it and hit 'Add as library') I don't see the option Add as Library when I right click on the jar file in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

put jar file on app->lib folder
and in your project build.gradle use compile ('libs/filename.jar')
then sync your project
this will work

Answer (score 0):

`File`->`Project Structure`->`Dependencies`->"+"->`File dependency`